# Firebase Analytics: Retention criteria

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I am looking into using Firebase Analytics for my apps. I'm curious:

What are the criteria for which retention is based on? Does retention track user accounts with a unique id that I'd have to send, or unique device?

How would I control for this if, say, a user logs into my app from multiple devices? I'd want to make sure a user's retention is applied from those multiple devices.

Answer (score 2):

The Firebase SDK library uses an app-instance identifier to Identify a unique installation of the App. When using the SDK, an app-instance identifier gets generated at the app level (Source: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318039?hl=en).

There is also a thing called **User Properties** that you can use to have a better understanding about unique users i.e. users that signed into your app (Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users)